# how to create a custom AutoComplete function like inbuilt Autocomplete function?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, ado.net

i want to create a autocomplete function like inbuilt autocomplete where when we type in combobox's text editor filed a matching suggestion comes out like this:

[image]

i don't want to use inbuilt AutoCompleteMode.
i have created a AutoCompleteStringCollection named collection and filled it with my database data.
i really don't know where to start as i am very new to programming and i searched for it all over the internet but found nothing related to it. i am really stuck, please help.

i tried this but i knew it will not work as i want

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string s in collection)
        {
            if (s.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                comboBox1.Text = s;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the easiest way use third-party components like devexpress.

Comment: @jvnd i am a learner and can't afford devexpress services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to achieve the autocompleted function in the combobox.

```
      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] source = new string[] { "Jack", "Jassie", "Junk", "Jungle" };
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection combData = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        combData.AddRange(source);
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = combData;
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(source);
    }
    int i = 1;
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && (keyData == Keys.Down))
        {
            if(i%2!=0)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                i++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                int index = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text) + 1;
                if(index<comboBox1.Items.Count)
                {
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text) + 1;
                    textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                    i++;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                  
                    return true;
                }
               
            }
           
            
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks i want like when i type "ja" autocomplete shows me first possible match "jack" and when i press downKey key it should not move to next match "jassie" but it should select "jack" as selected index and after that when i again press down arrow key  it should select next index after "jack" index but in my case when i press down arrow key autocomplete keeps selected "ja"  and search for next match starts with "ja". if you dont use autocomplete and type "ja" it will suggest nothing  but when you press downKey it will select "jack". i want this same functionality but it should suggest "jack".

Comment: @prashant, I have updated my code based on your requirement, please check if it works for you.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i did some tweaks in the code and now it is working like i wanted. i am putting what i did in answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if ((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && keyData == Keys.Down && i == 0)
        {
            
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
                comboBox1.SelectAll();
                i = 1;
                return true;
        }
        else if((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && keyData == Keys.Down && i == 1)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < comboBox1.Items.Count -1)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex++;
                comboBox1.SelectAll();
            }
            return true;
        }
        if ((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && keyData == Keys.Up && i == 0)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(comboBox1.Text);
            comboBox1.SelectAll();
            i = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else if((this.ActiveControl == comboBox1) && keyData == Keys.Up && i == 1 )
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex--;
            comboBox1.SelectAll();
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
```